# Cross-domain policy issues after redirect in Flash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, cross-domain

I'm having trouble with a cross-domain policy. I'm using the AS3 Loader to fetch an image; I'm making it load the policy file, like this :

```
var pLoader : Loader = new Loader();            

var pContext : LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
pContext.checkPolicyFile = true;

pLoader.load(new URLRequest(sURL), pContext);
```

This works fine as long as the image is directly accessible; **however**, when the server sends a redirect, the loader follows it but loses the checkPolicyFile flag, resulting in a SecurityException - that is, it doesn't check the cross-domain policy of the redirected URL.

I've found a solution here ( http://www.stevensacks.net/2008/12/23/solution-as3-security-error-2122-with-300-redirects ) but looks fragile (that is, looks like it will fail if there's more than one redirect). What would be the correct way of doing this?

EDIT : My currently best solution is to use a new Loader if accessing the content throws a SecurityException AND the loaded URL is different than the one I requested originally... works, but feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://www.arpitonline.com/blog/2008/06/17/debugging-crossdomain-issues-following-http-302s/